# I want to delete all rows from a dataframe based on names in a named integer

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(701*5), nrow=701))
my_vector <- sample(100:500, 13)
my_names <- sample(100:500, 13)
names(my_vector) <- my_names
```

I need a code that deletes specific rows from df. Which rows to delete? Check names from my_vector.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this

```
rows_to_delete <- as.numeric(names(my_vector))
df_filtered <- df[-rows_to_delete,]
```

I was not using as.numeric and hence kept getting error.